# navigation controller issue in application with 2 tabs

Tags: ios

In my application 2 tabs are there. I am adding tabbarController to the window with two view controllers viewcontroller1 and viewcontroller2 in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions. Now I need to add a button in the viewcontroller1 and in the button action i need to push a new viewcontroller nextViewController. To do this in the button action, i had created a navigation controller and sets its rootview controller as viewcontroller1 and then i push the nextViewController through that navigation controller. But the nextViewController is not getting loaded. Why?

- (void) buttonAction {

UINavigationController *navController=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:self];

nextViewController *nextViewControllerObj = [[nextViewController alloc]init];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:nextViewControllerObj animated:YES];

}

Comment: Please put code of how you are navigating to nextViewController

Comment: hey.. you need to show people some code get the right answer..:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of adding first tab view controller into UINavigationController, please try adding main UITabBarController into UINavigationController in "didFinishLaunchingWithOptions".

Comment: I added UINavigationController as a viewcontroller to UITabBarController. Then it is working. But why previously it was not working?

Comment: Oh, super! You created new UINavigationController, which is not been pushed and so not available in the navigation controller stack. To use a navigation controller, it must be added to window rootview controller or one of the view controller must be pushed using this UINavigationController. This is my guess.